# How to calculate probability in normal distribution with R

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

There is a variable **M** with normal distribution N(μ, σ), where μ=100 and σ = 10.

Find the probability P{|M-80|≥ 11}?

What I did using R was:

1. P{|M-80|≥ 11} = P{|M|≥ 11 + 80} = P{|M|≥ 91}
2. pnorm(91, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = FALSE)

But it's incorrect!,  please can you tell me what's the correct way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did the absolute value conversion wrong

P{|M-80|>=11} = P{M>=91} + P{M=<69}

```
pnorm(91, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = FALSE) +
    pnorm(69, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting 80 just changes the mean, try:

```
pnorm(11,20,10,lower=FALSE)+pnorm(-11,20,10)
```

which is not the same as:

```
pnorm(91, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = FALSE)+
pnorm(-91, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = TRUE)
```

but:

```
pnorm(91, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = FALSE)+
pnorm(69, mean=100, sd=10, lower.tail = TRUE)
```