# normally distributed population, calculating in R the probability of negative or zero readings occurring

Tags: r, helper, anova, cheminformatics

In R, how do you calculate the probability of negative or zero readings occurring?
μ and σ are giving.

Comment: There are many similiar questions to this, e.g.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29476023/how-to-calculate-probability-in-normal-distribution-with-r https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545973/how-to-use-pnorm-in-r-to-calculate-the-probability-that-the-mean-of-n-random-var

Answer (score 3):

You can use the distribution function of the gaussian distribution:

```
pnorm(0,μ,σ)
```

(I guess you are speaking about gaussian distribution)

---

## edit

The pnorm is the cumulative density function. Its values are between 0 and 1, and its value at x gives the area under the gaussian curve from -inf to x. In my example below, the value at 0 of pnorm give the area in pink under the gaussian curve, so the probability you are looking for, i.e. the probability of sampling a value following the corresponding gausian distribution with a value below or equal to 0.

[image]

Comment: But why "0"? what does that mean?

Comment: @Mara.  The assumption is that you want the cdf,  F(x) <= 0 where x is normally distributed.  So for example, if m=4, sd=2, P(x<=0) = pnorm(0, 4, 2) = 0.0227.  The probability that x > 0 is simply 1 - prnorm(0, 4, 2).  You have to clarify if you want something else.